# Ionic + Angular2 google maps layer event listener model binding

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework, angular-ngmodel

I have a map initialized with markers. Whenever I click on a marker I want to update Ngmodel. Eventually this should reflect in a ion-searchbar. Whenever the view loads I call initMap() which loads the map together with this listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function(e) {
      this.searchValue = e.row['name'].value;
});
```

in my template:

```
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchValue"></ion-searchbar>
```

Whenever I set a value to searchValue at the declaration it does show in the ion-searchbar, however not after clicking a marker. The marker click event does work because if I console log e.row['name'].value , I get the correct value, it just not seems to bind.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping `this.searchValue = e.row['name'].value;` in the `NgZone` method `run()`? `this.zone.run(() => { this.searchValue = e.row['name'].value; });`

Comment: I have imported NGZone in my module now, also declared it in the constructor. Added this: this.zone.run(() => { this.searchValue = e.row['name'].value; }); in the addlistener method and im getting: Cannot read property 'run' of undefined

Comment: Just import `NgZone` in your component. Not in the module.

Comment: Sorry I did that in my component. Imported from from '@angular/core'. And in my constructor private zone: NgZone. Then your zone code in the addListener function. It then gives me that error.

Comment: I fixed it by doing:  google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', (e) => { 
        this.searchValue = e.row['name'].value; 
      }
    )};

However the value gets updated VERY slow. So when I click a marker it updates after like 10+ seconds. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Same error with public and NGZone.run isn't allowed somehow. I got it working with the above code, it just updates ridiculously slow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150549/discussion-between-davida-and-robbannn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing `NgZone` and make use of its [`run()`](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#run)-method, to explicitly make the code run inside Angulars zone, and also trigger change detection afterwards. Also change `function(e){...}` to [`(e) => {}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which is non-binding of `this`.

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    ...
})
export class SomeComponent{
    someValue: string;

    constructor(private zone: NgZone){}

    initMap(){
        ...
        google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', (e) => {
            this.zone.run(() => {  
                this.searchValue = e.row['name'].value;
            });
        });
    }

    ...
}
```